# Position not work well for email template in safari

Tags: css, safari, position, fixed, email-templates

I am trying to create one email template have one footer and wants to fix in Bottom of the email template, Is there any way? Appreciate in advance.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried so far. Start by sharing the template that you have so far.

Comment: You can make it static on mobile devices but not on all email clients. It will not work on some email clients like Outlook.

Comment: @ClockSlave Agree, will take care..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSS answer. You 'build up' from this corner. An imported image may help with looks. I used the hash tag to make it a division class. Only a division can have a z-index assigned to it.

```css
<style>
#e_mail_template {position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;z-index:1000;}
</style>
```

NOTE: Read Syfers comment: "You can make it static on mobile devices but not on *all* email clients. It will not work on some email clients like Outlook."

Also note that a fixed position with a z-index of 1000 will place this (and the divisions contents) above all other objects.

Comment: This will not work on some email clients like Outlook.

Comment: @Syfer. The OP did not mention Outlook as a requirement. But any email can emulate HTML format unless it is forced to be text only.

Comment: Its not about requirement, when an answer is given you can give a disclaimer that it will not work on all email clients. Emails are nothing like Web, no standards and buggy support for everything all over.

Comment: You can still add it to your answer from my comment to OP. Its better to give tips then to down vote ;-)